# Spark set_hadoop_config error

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

Does anyone know what is causing this error? Looks so basic.

In:

```
def set_hadoop_config(credentials):
prefix = "fs.swift.service." + credentials['name']
hconf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hconf.set(prefix + ".auth.url", credentials['auth_url']+'/v2.0/tokens')
hconf.set(prefix + ".auth.endpoint.prefix", "endpoints")
hconf.set(prefix + ".tenant", credentials['project_id'])
hconf.set(prefix + ".username", credentials['user_id'])
hconf.set(prefix + ".password", credentials['password'])
hconf.setInt(prefix + ".http.port", 8080)
hconf.set(prefix + ".region", credentials['region'])
```

Out:

> Name: Compile Error Message: :1: error: ':' expected but ')'
>   found.
>          def set_hadoop_config(credentials):
>                                           ^ StackTrace:

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a syntax error. Somewhere in your code, you've placed a parentheses when you should have placed a colon

Comment: This is a new notebook and the 1st lines of code unfortunately. Thx

Comment: When I execute the code as shown in your question, I get an error about missing indentation in the second line. When I indent all but the first line, it executes without a problem. I tried in a newly created notebook.
Maybe there's some whitespace or other special character that you overlooked in the actual code?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with this code.

1. It is a Python code snippet, but executed within Scala Kernel, which demands valid Scala code. You can switch kernels by using the Kernel->Change Kernel menu option. This is the reason for the `CompileError` you are seeing.
2. If executed with a Python Kernel, you will receive an `IndentationError`, because the function body is not indented correctly. Use instead:

```
    def set_hadoop_config(credentials):
      prefix = "fs.swift.service." + credentials['name']
      hconf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
      hconf.set(prefix + ".auth.url", credentials['auth_url']+'/v2.0/tokens')
      hconf.set(prefix + ".auth.endpoint.prefix", "endpoints")
      hconf.set(prefix + ".tenant", credentials['project_id'])
      hconf.set(prefix + ".username", credentials['user_id'])
      hconf.set(prefix + ".password", credentials['password'])
      hconf.setInt(prefix + ".http.port", 8080)
      hconf.set(prefix + ".region", credentials['region'])
```

(Tip: In the notebook, select the complete function body and hit `Tab` once to indent it)